# How can I "cast" a javascript object to a child class?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, sockets, extends

I'm porting a game written in an ancient language to javascript/node. My initial plan for the server/client part was to create a separate class for the server and the client. For the server, I extend `EventEmitter`, create and store a `net.Server` object as a member variable, and expose a listen method on my class.

Where I'm running into design questions is with the client. The `net.Socket` is created by the `net.createServer` function and passed into my callback:

```js
const server = net.createServer(socket => {
    // somehow turn socket into a Client object here
    // let client = new Client(socket); ???
});
```

So my initial thought was to pass this socket as a constructor arg into my `Client` class:

```js
class Client extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(socket) {
        super();
        this._socket = socket;
    }

    // example wrapper method
    write(buff) {
        debug(/* print the buffer in hex */);
        this._socket.write(buff);
    }

    // example new method
    sendMessage(message) {
        let buff = Buffer.alloc(4 + message.length);
        buff.writeInt32LE(message.length);
        buff.write(message);
        this.write(buff);
    }        

    // other methods
}
```

But I'm finding myself writing a lot of wrapper methods to the internal socket. It makes me think that what I really want is to have the `Client` be a superclass of net.Socket. But then I have to somehow "cast" the socket that the `Server` creates into my `Client` class. The problem is that the `Client`'s constructor sets up some state variables that this socket then wouldn't have if I just "cast" it to my `Client` class.

Are there any generally accepted design patterns for situations like this? Situation being that I want to extend an existing object with new methods and state in the cleanest way possible. I've been thinking of the alternatives but I can't decide if anything is better:

- create a [proxy](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:direct_proxies) between the Client instance and the internal socket
- use Object.extend to fill the socket object with the methods I need
- stick to manually proxying any methods I need on the socket

Comment: Why not add a method to `Server` that creates the a `Client`? The `Server` already knows what socket you need.

Comment: @ssube The server is sort of creating the client within the createServer callback. What I'm wondering is more of how to turn node's Socket object into my Client object.

Comment: check out https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inherits_constructor_superconstructor

Comment: @Catalyst I'm using es6 classes which support extends, which I think does the same thing as that. The problem I'm facing is that the socket instance already exists, I don't have control over how it is created.

Comment: hummm.... well given your needs, are you opposed to writing an adapter for the Socket? You could then change the DI for Client constructor to just require an interface and use any adapter that satisfies that interface requirement.

Comment: You can't just turn an object of one type into another. You can, however, take the socket in the client's constructor as @CorvusCrypto points out. With or without DI, that ought to do it.

Comment: You could always reassign the prototype of the socket's prototype to be whatever you want. Mangling the prototype chain is all good, it is essentially a linked list.